# Replace for resolveSizeAndState for API 10?

Tags: android

What could be the best method for resolveSizeAndState to be able use in API 10 android? 
I've searched around and I've stuck.

I've rewritted the src code to this, it works anyway but is it safe?

```
private int resolveSizeAndState2(int size, int measureSpec, int childMeasuredState) {
    int result = size;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
    switch (specMode) {
    case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        result = size;
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        if (specSize < size) {
            result = specSize | MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL;
        } else {
            result = size;
        }
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
        result = specSize;
        break;
    }
    return result | (childMeasuredState&MEASURED_STATE_MASK);
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you found a answer ? :)

Comment: If anyone comes across this, there's an implementation in `ViewCompat`

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
ViewCompat.resolveSizeAndState()
```

should work